# Spring Cloud: Microservice authentication works through Eureka Discovery, but not through Zuul

Tags: java, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-security

I'm kind of new to Spring Cloud. I'm trying to build a few microservices by using Spring Cloud Eureka Discovery and Zuul Gateway.

I can access the microservices and perform actions through Zuul Gateway, but only when there is no security involved. If my microservice is secured, then I cannot do anything through Zuul as it doesn't return back a JWT token. If I do it through Eureka discovery client it works like a charm.

Maybe there is something wrong with my Zuul configuration? Or maybe I have chosen an invalid way to secure the services? Thanks in advance!

***Here is my Zuul Gateway configuration:***

**Application.class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class GatewayServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Filter shallowEtagHeaderFilter() {
        return new ShallowEtagHeaderFilter();
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8010/eureka/
server.port=8011
zuul.prefix=/services
```

**bootstrap.properties**

```
spring.application.name=gateway-service
# specify where config server is up
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8001
```

***Here is my microservice JWT & security configuration:***

**WebSecurityConfig.class**

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                // We filter the api/login requests
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                // And filter other requests to check the presence of JWT in header
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure (AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // Create a default account
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("**")
                .password("**")
                .roles("**");
    }
}
```

**TokenAuthenticationService.class**

```
public class TokenAuthenticationService {
    static final long EXPIRATIONTIME = 864_000_000; // 10 days
    static final String SECRET = "*";
    static final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer";
    static final String HEADER_STRING = "Authorization";

    static void addAuthentication (HttpServletResponse res, String username) {
        String JWT = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(username)
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATIONTIME))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET)
                .compact();
        res.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + " " + JWT);
    }

    static Authentication getAuthentication (HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
        if (token != null) {
            // parse the token.
            String user = Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(SECRET)
                    .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                    .getBody()
                    .getSubject();

            return user != null ?
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, Collections.emptyList()) :
                    null;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**JWTLoginFilter.class**

```
public class JWTLoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    public JWTLoginFilter (String url, AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(url));
        setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication (HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

        AccountCredentials creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(req.getInputStream(), AccountCredentials.class);
        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        creds.getUsername(),
                        creds.getPassword(),
                        Collections.emptyList()
                )
        );

    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication (HttpServletRequest req,
                                             HttpServletResponse res,
                                             FilterChain chain,
                                             Authentication auth)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        TokenAuthenticationService.addAuthentication(res, auth.getName());
    }
}
```

**JWTAuthenticationFilter.class**

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    @Override
    public void doFilter (ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        Authentication authentication = TokenAuthenticationService.getAuthentication((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you remove 'Authorization' header form sensitiveHeaders list ? sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie,Authorization are defaults. So Authroization headers are filltered out by zuul proxy. If you need it, declare sensitiveHeaders w/o Authorization header.

Comment: @yongsung.yoon you mean this? `zuul.sensitive-headers=Authorisation`

Comment: You can define sensitive headers for each route. You need to re-declare it without Authroization to allow Authorization header field. Please refere "Cookies and Sensitive Headers" section in http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html

Comment: @yongsung.yoon `zuul.routes.users.path=/myusers/**
zuul.routes.users.sensitiveHeaders=Cookie,Set-Cookie,Authorization
zuul.routes.users.url=downstream` like this?

Comment: Right. Also as you wrote, you can define it globally with "zuu.sensitive-headers=Cookie, Set-Cookie". You need to REMOVE "Authorization" from the list because it's default

Comment: Still doesn't work :( `zuul.routes.users.path=/myusers/**
zuul.sensitive-headers=Cookie,Set-Cookie,Authorization
zuul.routes.users.sensitiveHeaders=Cookie,Set-Cookie,Authorization
zuul.routes.users.url=downstream`

Comment: 'users' should be replaced with your routing name (serivce ID). And remove Authorization from the list.

Comment: Just try "zuul.sensitiveHeaders=Cookie,Set-Cookie"  after removing previous one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142051/discussion-between-deniss-m-and-yongsung-yoon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to define the below.

```
zuul.sensitiveHeaders=Cookie,Set-Cookie
```

In zuul, Cookie, Set-Cookie and Authroization headers are default sensitive headers. If you want to Authroization header in your api server, you need to redefine it without `Authroization` header like above.

Also you can define it for each route. 
Please refer to the doc : http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html [Cookies and Sensitive Headers]